# Setup new bitbucket repo. can clone but cannot push

Tags: git, bitbucket

just set up a new repo on bitbucket.
I am trying to push for the first time and when i do i get the error

```
git push origin master
Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can clone the repo just fine

When i do this command

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled

# git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myproject/reggie.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myproject/reggie.git (push)
```

I think with that and the clone i have the correct ssh keys

Any other things i can do to debug or settings that i am not doing in bitbucket?

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @matt i updated the text with an answer to your question